Disable Bluetooth Headset Buttons
I have a Samsung Galaxy A71 5G (non-rooted) and a pair of Sony WFC510 headphones. I have a problem with the buttons of the earbuds being accidentally pressed when I lay down. Normally there's an app from the manufacturer I can use to disable them but with this specific Sony device there's no help.
